# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'EuclideanDistance' on <module 'sklearn.metrics._dist_metrics'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, attributeerror

I have been attempting to run a simple code with the `interpvall` function but ran into the following error:

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'EuclideanDistance' on <module 'sklearn.metrics._dist_metrics' from '/Users/adamhitchmough/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_dist_metrics.cpython-38-darwin.so'>
```

My code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import os
import sklearn

interpvall = pd.read_pickle('/Users/adamhitchmough/Downloads/KNN_swi_Vall_k50000.pkl')
```

I have upgraded my `sklearn` package as instructed to do so by other forums but this did not resolve the error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your `Scikit-Learn` version?

Comment: @Goku-standswithPalestine 1.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this version:

```
pip install scikit-learn==1.2.2
```

`sklearn.metrics._dist_metrics` module has `EuclideanDistance()` and `EuclideanDistance32()`.

I think, `version 1.3.2` has `EuclideanDistance32()` and `EuclideanDistance64()`, instead.